# How to combine static mappings when using Abstract classes on Domain Classes in Grails 5

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-domain-class

We have a plugin that gives us an Abstract class called `PaymentAbstract`

It looks like this.

```
abstract class PaymentAbstract implements Serializable {

    static mapping = {
        tablePerHierarchy false  // avoid creating the base_domain table
        tablePerConcreteClass true
        token defaultValue: "-1"
        ...
    }

    String token
    Date authDate
    ...
}
```

In our apps we create a Payment that extends the abstract class like this.

```
class Payment extends PaymentAbstract {
    String foo
    ...
}
```

A problem arises when we want to add a mapping formula.

```
class Payment extends PaymentAbstract {

    static mapping = {
        bar formula: "..."
        ...
    }

    String token
    Date authDate
    ...
}
```

But this overwrites the original mapping and we lose a lot of details on the payment.

Is there any way to merge both of these static mappings?

Comment: Did you try to update the cascadeValidate property? In the [docs](https://gorm.grails.org/latest/hibernate/manual/index.html#constraints) show one example

Comment: I'm not referencing another entity so I'm not sure how to apply the cascadeValidate example to my situation.